# Call C++ DLL function through nodejs web API

Tags: node.js, express, dll, nodes, node-modules

I wrote a C# dll file with functions that return some values. I am trying to call dll functions through node.js web Api to get some return values. But I don't get Any proper information on how I can do this.

```
example.com/getinfo
```

Please support how i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register the dll file. The file on example.com needs to be allowed in your configuration of your web server. It also may need to be in the right location/folder to be accessed and have the correct rights to execute. It would help if you mentioned what kind of server is serving web pages. Apache - IIS etc.